# Children views are null after inflate

Tags: android, android-layout

Okay so I do this (not actual code)

```
try {
    final View view = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.ownComponent, null);
} catch (InflateExpection e) {
}

if (view != null) {
    // This child is null about 5/10 times!

    View child = view.findViewById(R.id.ownComponentChild);
}
```

I read that after inflate it is not guaranteed that child views are inflated, so what would be neat way to get callback when all childs are ready?

Comment: In which context do you use that code ?

Comment: first add something in the catch scope.. or you'll never know if the inflate failed.

Comment: this is used in own implementation of Gallery component getView function. This is not actual code, but very similar so the inflateExpection is handled there.

Comment: paste your entire code/method...

Comment: Sorry cannot paste that, it is confidential code, but you get the point from the small snippet. I think this happens sometimes because the are so many views to inflate and childs in them that the hardware just cannot be fast enough.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to happen randomly so my only guess is that memory is getting low in this case, because I have to recreate so many UI components fast to get this reproduced.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe I misunderstood what you're trying to do, but it seems like you're inflating a `View` and not a layout...

Try

```
View view = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.LAYOUT_THAT_HOLDS_ownComponent, this, true);
```

and then view will hold the entire layout, from which you can find the child by Id with

```
view.findViewById(...);
```

**Edit:**

Hard to know if it's related as you didn't post enough code but try this:
Get the `View view` out of the try/catch and put it as a class member. loose the final and cast the child.

example (assuming ownComponentChild is a FrameLayout):

`FrameLayout child = (FrameLayout)view.findViewById(R.id.ownComponentChild);`

Comment: The view actually is FrameLayout and the code works 5/10 times.

Comment: @Niko still, why do you inflate a specific view? inflate the layout XML that holds the FrameLayout and then you'll be able to find its children with findViewById(R.id.ownComponentChild); Notice the difference between inflate(R.layout...) to your inflate(R.id...)

Comment: Most of the time children views can be found all right and no null pointer expections are seen. Inflating to root and attachToRoot = true didn't make any difference.

Comment: Also updated the code, I am inflating a layout not view, typo when wrote the code snippet there.

Comment: Doesn't make any difference, the problem here is that inflate is not synchronous to inflate all childrens, only the layout itself.

Comment: @Niko not seeing the rest of the code, I have no other suggestion.. I did this so many times and never had an issue like this. It either works or not but sometimes work and sometimes not is something I didn't encounter. Sorry... Please share you solution if you'll solve it eventually.

Comment: Sure I will, this is the first time to me too to see this, always thought that after inflating all the views can be accessed with findViewById and they never being null.